# float like with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to do something with my website, I have a series of squares which are filling a flexbox in a row direction, the problem is that I have the first of those square that is more like a big rectangle taking 2 squares and I would like to have the square fill the remaining space on the right of the square.

I found a way to do it with grid layout but it is still experimental and I cant make them work on current version of the major browsers; so I was wondering is there a way to do this with normal flexbox?

here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1dkkjhae/

thank you in advance

```
    *{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Segoe UI,OpenSans,Noto,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,FreeSans,sans-serif;
    }

    h1{
      font-weight: 100;
      border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
      width: 1060px;
      height: 45px;
      margin: 0 10px;
    }

    header{
      display:flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 110px;
      background: #505050;
    }

    #banniere{
      display:flex;
      margin: auto;
      flex-direction: row;
      width: 1080px;
      height: 110px;
      padding: 5px; 
    }

    #logo{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #00c308;
      margin: 0px 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-top: 40px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    .boutons{
      margin: 0px 10px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #00c308;
      padding: 5px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 100;
      background: purple;
    }

    #user{
      display: flex;
      align-self: baseline;
      width: 150px;
      height: 75px;
      background: #00c308;
    }

    nav{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      border-top: 1px #D1D1D1 solid;
      position: static;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background: #5d5d5d;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px grey;
    }

    #menu{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1080px;
    }

    nav ul{
      display: flex;
      max-width: 1080px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 49px;
      list-style: none;
    }

    nav ul li{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex: 1;
      text-align: center;
      background: #5d5d5d;
    }

    nav ul li a{
      box-sizing: content-box;
      padding: 11px 0px;
      width:100%;
      font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue" ;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #EEEEEE;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    .sous_menu{
      position: relative;
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .sous_menu a{
      color: black;
    }

    .sous_menu a:hover{
      background: #00ce08;
    }

    nav ul li a:hover{
      color: white;
      background: #00c308;
    }

    nav ul li:hover>.sous_menu{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    #container{
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      max-width: 1080px;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 700px;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #news{
      margin: 10px;
      max-width: 1060px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      background: grey;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
    }

    #articles{
      max-width: 1080px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .categories{
      display:flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      max-width: 1080px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .carte{
      position: relative;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      background: grey;
      margin: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .filtres{
      position: relative;
      width: 250px;
      height: 510px;
      background: grey;
      margin: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    footer{
      bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #505050;
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

Comment: As `flexbox` is not a "grid system" it is not possible (you can use JS to adjust it with margins of course).. good to go with masonary or CSS columns...